# Django queryset : Handle table with .distinct() and .count()

Tags: python, django, count, distinct

I would like to handle some `Django` tables in order to create a statistic table in my HTML template.

For example, I need to get all `distinct object` from my database table, display `the count of each distinct object`, ...

***Example :***

I have a table named `Download` which looks like this :

```
#TABLE DOWNLOAD
 ____________________________________________
| email                | PUB (FK_DOCUMENT)   |
| __________________________________________ |
|test12@gmail.com      | 1                   |   
| __________________________________________ |
|test12@gmail.com      | 2                   | 
| __________________________________________ |
|test45@gmail.com      | 4                   | 
| __________________________________________ |
|test22@gmail.com      | 3                   | 
| __________________________________________ |
|test01@gmail.com      | 2                   | 
| __________________________________________ |
|test98@gmail.com      | 4                   | 
| __________________________________________ |
|test74@gmail.com      | 4                   | 
| __________________________________________ |
```

This table has a ForeignKey according to table named `Document` :

```
#TABLE DOCUMENT
 __________________
| ID     | EDQM_ID |
| ________________ |
|1       | A       |   
| ________________ |
|2       | B       |
| ________________ |
|3       | C       |  
| ________________ |
|4       | D       | 
| ________________ |
```

I would like to create an HTML table like this :

```
#HTML STATISTICS TABLE
 ________________________
| PUB_ID     | Requests |
| _____________________ |
|A           | 1        |   
| _____________________ |
|B           | 2        |
| _____________________ |
|C           | 1        |  
| _____________________ |
|D           | 3        | 
| _____________________ |
```

Where :

- `PUB_ID` corresponds to distinct `PUB_ID` from table `Download`
- `Requests` corresponds to sum of each `PUB_ID` occurence from table `Download`

This is my queryset for `PUB_ID` :

```
pub_id = Download.objects.values_list('pub__edqm_id').distinct()
```

It returns :

```
<QuerySet [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)]>
```

And my queryset for `Requests` :

```
requests = Download.objects.values_list('pub__edqm_id').annotate(count=Count('pub__edqm_id'))
```

It returns :

```
<QuerySet [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 1), ('D', 3)]>
```

***Question :***

How I can populate my HTML table :

```
<table id="DocumentTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table_model">
      <thead>
      <caption style="border: inherit; background-color: lightgrey;">
            <span><strong>Download per Publication</strong></span>
      </caption>
      <tr>
        <th>{% trans 'Publications' %}</th>
        <th>{% trans 'Requests' %}</th>
        <th>{% trans 'Max download number' %}</th>
        <th>{% trans 'Average download number' %}</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for item in pub_id %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ item }}</td>
          <td><span class="badge alert-danger"> Requests here </span></td>
          <td> </td>
          <td> </td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

It displays in my table :

```
('A',)
('B',)
...
```

And this is my view :

```
class StatsView(View):
    template_name = 'freepub/stats.html'

    def get(self, request):
        subtitle = _("Statistics")

        #Some values display in my template
        customers_count = Customer.objects.all().count()
        publications_count = Publication.objects.all().count()
        downloads_count = Download.objects.all().count()
        last_download_temp = Download.objects.latest('id').download_date
        last_download = last_download_temp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ')
        document = Document.objects.all()

        #Populate HTML table
        pub_id = Download.objects.values_list('pub__edqm_id').distinct()

        fieldname = Download.objects.values_list('pub__edqm_id').annotate(count=Count('pub__edqm_id'))

        context = {'subtitle': subtitle,
                   'fieldname': fieldname,
                   'customers_count': customers_count,
                   'publications_count': publications_count,
                   'downloads_count': downloads_count,
                   'last_download': last_download,
                   'document': document}

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
downloads = Download.objects.values('pub__edqm_id').annotate(count=Count('pub__edqm_id'))
context = {'downloads': downloads, ....
```

And in the template

```
{% for download in downloads %}
{{ download.pub__edqm_id }} {{ download.count }}
{% endfor %}
```